# VS 2019 remote debugging without network connection?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a standalone machine, that is not connected to the network. Can I connect with my laptop to the machine with a USB-cable (or direct Network cable) and use the Remote Debugging features?

Comment: [The configuration dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-cpp#BKMK_setup) does have "computers are directly connected over Ethernet" option. Haven't used that myself.

Comment: Where do you see this option? I see only TCP/IP port number to chose.